# php session only working locally: php, database, ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, forms

I'm working on a website that uses google maps to take your browser location and uses a form to take 2 other fields.  All four are submitted to a database.  The geolocation works fine on all computers, but the form submission produces null results on every computer except mine.  On mine, it works both locally and on the website.  I have taught myself what I know and I am totally stumped.  Help please?

Here is the relevant code:

index.php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"> 
       <span class="error">#<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"></span>
       <span class="error">*</span>
       <br><br>
       <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30">Comment</textarea><br>
       <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
       <span class="error"><br> must allow browser geolocation to submit entry</span>
    </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
      { 
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['id'];
        $_SESSION['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];
        session_write_close();
      }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function geolocate(){
        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var lat = pos.lat();
            var lng = pos.lng();
            ////**********************************************************************************

               $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'scripts/submit.php',
                    data: {
                        lat: lat,
                        lng: lng
                    },
                    crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function( data ) {
                        //console.log( data );
                    }//,
                    //beforeSend: setHeader
                });

            ////**********************************************************************************
          }, function() {           //end get current position
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });   //end function set to true
        } 
        else { //end if there's geolocation
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }   //end else
      }//end geolocate

      geolocate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();

require("phpsql_dbinfo.php");

$id = $_SESSION['number'];
$comment =$_SESSION['comment'];
$lat = $_GET[lat];
$lng = $_GET[lng];

//database
//OPEN
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","$username","$password","$database");





// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



    //insert into database
    //$sql="INSERT INTO markers (lat, lng, id, comment, icon) VALUES ('$lat', '$lng', '$id', '$comment', '$icon')";
 $sql="INSERT INTO markers (lat, lng, number, comment) VALUES ('$lat', '$lng', '$id', '$comment')";

    // if problem with query
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

//CLOSE
mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

When submitted, the form sets the session variables, then uses ajax to pass the latitude and longitude to submit.php.  All are retrieved in submit.php.

I can't find my answer online anywhere and I'm not getting any errors.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably got two different domains and PHP sessions is different as well.

Comment: You have a mix of POST and GET methods/variables. Try changing it to `$lat = $_REQUEST[lat]; $lng = $_REQUEST[lng];` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: I tried switching to $_REQUEST, but no go.  Still works on mine, still null on others